# I want to generate an object of objects, who also contain objects, based on WP categories/subcategories

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, ecmascript-5

I've been working with WP REST Api to migrate an app to a headless wp + react app and got some problems with how WP displays Cats and SubCats.

My idea is to get all the current categories and generate children of based on the father category, those children also can get childrens, since WP cat-subcat structure is infinite.

`Category { SubCategory { SubCategory {infinite}}}`

I've been trying to generate a new Object that contains this info and iterate in different ways, like pushing the one who has 'parentId' equals to father ID, but constantly getting undefined.

My current logic is something like this:

```
const fatherCategories = categories.filter((item) => (
   item.parent === 0
))

const subCategories = categories.filter((item) => (
   item.parent !== 0
))

const subCategories = subCats.forEach((category) => (
   subCats.filter((item) => (
      category.id === item.parent
   ))
))
```

Im 100% that this is not the way i need to get my objective but my knowledge stops here and can't get any solution for this problem, if i know the lenght of the subcategories i will go another way, but without this data, im blocked.

Comment: I think a recursion should be sufficient to do the trick here. You can create a single function which checks if it's a top one or not.

Comment: The point is, i've a plain json without no sublevels that contains all, and i don't know who recursively do the trick. ```"id": 20,
"name": "Videos",
"parent": 16,
``` I can also have another that have the parent === id: 20, and there's where im lost :(

Comment: Please check my below answer, it can become a little intensive if there are too many levels as it's literally runs the loops **n x n** times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my previous comment says something like this should work for you:

```js
function isParent(category) {
  return category.parent === 0;
}

function findAllchildren(allCategories, currentCategory) {
  // const allCategories.filter()
  const currCatChildren = allCategories.filter(
    (c) => c.parent === currentCategory.id
  );
  if (currCatChildren.length) {
    currCatChildren.forEach((c) => {
      c.children = findAllchildren(allCategories, c);
    });
  }
  return currCatChildren;
}

const categories = [
  { id: 1, parent: 0, name: "pc -> 1" },
  { id: 2, parent: 0, name: "pc -> 2" },
  { id: 3, parent: 1, name: "cc -> 3>1" },
  { id: 4, parent: 2, name: "cc -> 4>2" },
  { id: 5, parent: 3, name: "cc -> 5>3" },
  { id: 6, parent: 4, name: "cc -> 6>4>1" },
  { id: 7, parent: 5, name: "cc -> 7>5>3>1" },
];

const finalCategoryTree = categories.filter(isParent).map((parentCategory) => {
  const tmp = { ...parentCategory };
  tmp.children = findAllchildren(categories, parentCategory);
  return tmp;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(finalCategoryTree));
```

Comment: This mindset is my goal to go i guess, thank you so much for your help, this is the correct answer.